# WebStorm && Android Studio set Proxy Failed

Tags: intellij-idea, proxy

I want to set HTTP Proxy for my IDE (WebStorm and Android Studio),but it failed，because JVM have some proxy settings..I have found other IDE(like eclipse) proxySetting like below:[change some IDE proxy but it still broken](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3IYi.png)

I have consider that maybe some use JVM's Application change it's jvm proxy settings,such like Charles?Is it possible to do so？

you have JVM property "https.proxyHost" set to 127.0.0.1". This may lead to incorrect behaviour, Proxy should be set in Setting

[Preference>Appearance & Behavior>System Settings>HTTP Proxy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxWvq.png)

```
2017-01-07 14:57:30,010 [ 445277]   INFO - ntellij.util.proxy.CommonProxy - <html>You have JVM property "https.proxyHost" set to "127.0.0.1".<br>This may lead to incorrect behaviour. Proxy should be set in Settings | HTTP Proxy<br>This JVM property is old and its usage is not recommended by Oracle.<br>(Note: It could have been assigned by some code dynamically.)
```

**How to use resolve it**

Comment: Do you found the solution. I have same problem in android studio.

Comment: no, I don't have found. I just changed computer. LOL

Comment: Maybe you can reinstall your computer

Answer (score 7):

One way to remove the proxy value is as follows:

- Go to Intellij Menu -> `Help -> Edit Custom VM Options`
- Include the following two properties which will unset already set proxy value

  ```
  -DhttpsProxyHost
  -DhttpsPorxyPort
  ```

Once you restart Intellij again with these values, the warning coming under menu **HTTP Proxy** should be removed.

Answer (score 2):

For Android Studio, go to **Menu -> Help -> Edit Custom VM Options**

Add system property:

```
-Dhttp.proxyHost
-Dhttp.proxyPort
-Dhttps.proxyHost
-Dhttps.proxyPort
-DsocksProxyHost
-DsocksProxyPort
```

Then restart IDE, It works for me.